# $L\subset C[0,1]$ be the set of all triple differentiable functions with $x(0)=x'(0)=x''(0)=0$ $Tx=x'''+x''$ show that $T$ has bounded inverse

Tags: functional-analysis

$L\subset C[0,1]$ be the set of all triple differentiable functions with $x(0)=x'(0)=x''(0)=0$ and $T$ be a linear operator

$$T:L\to C[0,1]$$ denoted by $(Tx)(t)=x'''(t)+x''(t)$

How to show $T^{-1}$ is bounded/continuous?

I tried to use Bounded Inverse Theorem showing T is onto and 1-1 but is there a more elegant way?How to prove it properly?

Comment: by the way how to show first A is bounded?

Comment: I would set : $h(t) =x''' (t) +x''(t) $ and solve in the form of an integral  $x$ in function of $h$ using variation of parameters technic from homogenous solution. You can see here for more infos https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: What is the norm on $L$?

Comment: isn't given explicitly but in what norm it makes T bounded?

Comment: Well, if the norm is simply the supremum norm, then I am not sure that $T$ is bounded. If it is the sup norm + the sup norm of the derivative + the sup norm of the second derivative + the sup norm of the third derivative, then $T$ will be bounded indeed.

Comment: The same would work if we took the maximum of these 4 norms instead of their sum.

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale, By assumption, the operator is defined in the space $C [0,1]$, therefore it is not bounded. Next, in the definition area, $\ker T=\{0\}$ -- therefore, the operator is injective and is a bijection onto its image. Finding the inverse operator by solving the Cauchy problem by the method of variation of constants, we can show that the image of the operator is all $C[0,1]$, and the inverse is bounded on $C[0,1]$ after the simple evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $L:=\{f\in C^{(3)}[0,1]: f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0\}$. This is a closed subset of $C^{(3)}[0,1]$ which is a Banach space. So $T:L\to C[0,1]$ is a linear operator between Banach spaces.

1. $T$ is bounded

We show that $T$ is continuous at $0$ and this is equivalent to $T$ being bounded. Suppose that $(f_n)\subset L$ with $f_n\to 0$ in one of the norms I mention in the comments. We must show that $Tf_n\to0$ uniformly. But since $Tf_n(t)=f_n'''(t)+f_n''(t)$ we have that $f_n'''\to0$ and $f_n''\to 0$ uniformly, so $Tf_n\to 0$ uniformly and we are done.

2. $T$ is NOT 1-1.

Note that if $T(f)=0$, i.e. $f'''+f''=0$, then $f''+f'=c_1$, so $f'(x)+f(x)=c_1x+c_2$. The solution of this 1st order o.d.e is given by $f(x)=e^{-x}\cdot(\int (c_1x+c_2)dx+C)=e^{-x}(\frac{c_1}{2}x^2+c_2x+C)$. So

$$\{e^{-x}p_2(x): p_2\text{ is a 2nd degree polynomial}\}\subset\ker(T)\neq\{0\} $$

Since $T$ is not 1-1, it is not invertible, since invertible operators are exactly those that are 1-1 and onto.

Comment: You forgot that the operator is defined on the subspace of $C[0,1]$ and therefore is not bounded. In addition, from the domain it follows that $\ker T=\{0\}$.